# How to include italics and subscripts in text on plot in R

Tags: r, text, plot

I am trying to include some model parameters on a plot in R using 'text' - here is an example:

```
text(1, 8, "t4 = 3.8")
```

I would like 't' to be in italics and '4' to be subscript. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

See the helpfile for `plotmath`

```
text(1, 8, expression(italic(t)[4] == 3.8))
```